# Can we configure Experience Cloud login to redirect users to different community portals based on their profile?

Tags: experience-cloud

Can we configure Experience Cloud login to redirect users to different community portals based on their profile?

My customer wants to have single community login to recognize different user groups and redirect them to different portals based on their profiles.

Is such requirement achievable by configuration or do I need custom code or custom login discovery handler class?

---

Updates about what I have tried so far.

1.This is possible to create Redirect Aura component with the following
Redirect.cmp file

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions">
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" required="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

and redirect.js file

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {        
            
            var url = component.get("v.url");
            var target = '_self';
            var features = ''; 
            location.replace(url, target, features);
            resolve();
               
        });
    }
})
```

and redirect.design file

```
<design:component label="Redirect">
    <design:attribute name="url" label="URL" description="URL to redirect to when the flow action is invoked." placeholder="https://" />
</design:component>
```

2. This is possible to create a flow to redirect to a different experience site and then use it in a login flow.

However, there are some problems with this approach.

1. Error happens 'This flow contains local actions, so this flow runs only in Lightning runtime.' with Gack Id.
2. To overcome this error, we need to check the checkbox `Render Flow in Lightning Runtime` which is disabled. We actually can hack Salesforce interfance and remove 'disabled="disabled"' from the HTML code to make this checkbox available and check it, however, this might be broken in the future, so this is very fragile workaround to fix the Gack Id.
3. If we do that, both sign up and login will be redirected, not only login, so user will not be able actually to setup the password and login.
4. Even if we redirect user, the flow will be invoked again, since the user will be considered as unauthenticated for the different Experience cloud site and the redirect will become recursive preventing user from login even if user has set password before.

The same thing would happen with Visualforce login flow.

If we create a Visualforce page x with the content

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="VFLoginFlowController" action="{!x}">
</apex:page>
```

and the controller

```
public class VFLoginFlowController {

    public PageReference x() {
        return Auth.SessionManagement.finishLoginFlow('https://domain.my.site.com/partnercentral');
    }

}
```

the user will be actually redirected to a login page, considering as unauthenticated

Comment: Out of the box, the login page is tied to the site, it's not a generic login for all sites. At least for external users with Community or similar licenses.